# Как сделать превью сайта?

Tags: javascript, html5, css

К примеру: есть список ссылок, рядом с ссылкой картинка. Как сделать так чтобы эта картинка была скрином с сайта на который ведет ссылка?

Comment: Не так давно меня тоже этот вопрос интересовал. Присоединяюсь

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Привет. Чтобы получить скриншот сайта можно воспользоваться бесплатным сервисом http://mini.s-shot.ru/. Пример использования такой:

```
function screen($url, $extn, $size, $format) 
{
    $url = 'http://mini.s-shot.ru/'.$extn.'/'.$size.'/'.$format.'/?'.urlencode($url);
    $str = file_get_contents($url);
    file_put_contents('screen.'.$format, $str); // тут лучше указать путь куда сохранять
}

screen('http://hashcode.ru', '1024x768', '600', 'jpeg');
```

Функция используя сервис создает скриншот сайта и сохраняет его в файл "screen.jpeg".
Потом можно подгрузить с помощью <img ...>